# Magento 2 : Catalog access by customer group

Tags: catalog, magento-community, magento-2.2.5, access

I want to restrict product by customer group.

For mapping, we added an attribute to product called **group_ids** where admin can select multiple customer groups

I want to restrict customer to access this product if their customer group is not assigned to the product.

I want to restrict product access from upsell,crosssell,related,wishlist,product page,category page, home page every where.

So i was looking for function where magento filter product by website.
i want to override it add my custom logic to filter but not able to find out that function

So if anyone knows about it then please provide me information of that function or if there any other way to do it

Answer (score 2):

I found magento event **catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after**

which is called after all basic limitations applied.

app/code/Mymodule/Catalogaccess/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after">
        <observer name="catalogaccess_filter" instance="Mymodule\Catalogaccess\Observer\BrandAccess" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/Mymodule/Catalogaccess/Observer/BrandAccess.php

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('manufacturer','218');
    return $this;
}
```