# How to close a purchase for specific customers in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to close a purchase for a specific customer when the value of his user attribute is suspended, but he can login the site. I need to close only the purchase for this customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by hide add to cart button for that user.

Check user is login or not. If user is loing that check that attribute value. If it is suspended that hide add to cart button.

This way you can achieve your requirement.

Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: and if before that he will have a product on the card ?

Comment: @RobinioTor In that case you need to hide Checkout button on cart page as well as checkout page on same condition. If you hide checkout button then no need to hide cart button. Because use can only add product to cart. User can not purchase product.

Answer (score 0):

You can create customer group and assign that customer to created customer group.

You will need to create custom module to manage accessibility for that customer group.

You can get idea from below link:

[Magento 2 : Catalog access by customer group](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238549/magento-2-catalog-access-by-customer-group)